# Find where field is older than 3 days

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb database with a data structure like this:

```
{ 
"_id" : "123456":, 
"Dates" : ["2014-02-05 09:00:15 PM", "2014-02-06 09:00:15 PM", "2014-02-07 09:00:15 PM"],
}
```

There are other stuff too but what I would like to do is pull data where Dates{$slice: -1} is older than 3 days. I have a query like this but it doesnt work:

```
db.posts.find({}, {RecoveryPoints:{$slice: -1} $lt: ISODate("2014-02-09 00:00:00 AM")})
```

I am beginning to think is not possible but I figured I would come here first. My guess is that I'll have to do this logic within my code.

**Edit:** I wanted to mention too that my goal is to return the entire record and not just the date that mathes it

Comment: Is this actually what you see for a record in the Mongo shell, or are you just abstracting. Because if it is those dates are strings. Also the date you are comparing in your example is less than the first item in the array, so that would not match even if your dates are in the right format. Makes the question hard to answer if you don't clear this up.

Comment: My apologies, I had made up the dates. Ill edit it for better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query has all the elements on the projection side and not the query side. Since you do not want to change the appearance of the document, then thee is no need to project.

This is actually a simple comparison as if you are always looking at the first element then you can use the dot "." notation form to look for it:

```
> db.dates.find({ "Dates.0": {$lt: ISODate("2014-02-09 00:00:00 AM") } }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "Dates" : [
            ISODate("2014-02-05T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-06T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-07T09:00:15Z")
    ]
}
> db.dates.find({ "Dates.0": {$lt: ISODate("2014-02-05 00:00:00 AM") } }).pretty()
>
```

So the dot "." notation works at index value in the case of arrays, and to get other elements just change the position:

```
> db.dates.find({ "Dates.1": {$lt: ISODate("2014-02-07 00:00:00 AM") } }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "Dates" : [
            ISODate("2014-02-05T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-06T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-07T09:00:15Z")
    ]
}
> db.dates.find({ "Dates.3": {$lt: ISODate("2014-02-07 00:00:00 AM") } }).pretty()
>
> db.dates.find({ "Dates.2": {$lt: ISODate("2014-02-08 00:00:00 AM") } }).pretty()
{
    "_id" : "123456",
    "Dates" : [
            ISODate("2014-02-05T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-06T09:00:15Z"),
            ISODate("2014-02-07T09:00:15Z")
    ]
}
```

Note that this only makes sense if you are sorting the array on changes and can otherwise be sure that the first (or position you are querying ) element is going to be the one you want to compare. If you need to otherwise test against all elements, then use the [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator in the query instead.

The only reason you wouldn't get the result you want with this query is where your dates are strings. If so, change them, and change whatever code is causing them to be saved that way.